# All my css and js does not work if there is even a single line of code written in the .htaccess file, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, external

All my css and js external files does not work (they are not read or they are read wrongly by the browser) if there is even a single line of code written in the .htaccess file, how to fix it? Is there some kind of config that erases all previous mimes if I write a line in .htaccess?

**Details**:

Server:Apache
Mimes working: All html, htm and php files work.
Failing mimes so far: css and js. They are currently being loaded as php files with forced headings.
Text in .htaccess: Its nothing specific that i need to write on the htaccess, any single line of any code makes the css and js fails. (Example of single line code: "ServerSignature Off")

Comment: Show us what you have been writing in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: You should provide more details. Do you get other file types, like HTML files, work correctly after you write something in `.htaccess` file? What's your directory structure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my details: Server:Apache; All html, htm and php files work. Its nothing specific that i need to write on the htaccess, any single line of any code makes the css and js fails.

Comment: How about an example of any single line that makes it fail?

Comment: Also, what appears in your Apache error log?

Comment: I updated my post with more detailed information. And about the logs, there is nothing mentioning any error on reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

If that line happens to be RewriteURL for a minify script for instance, that doesn't send the proper Content-Type headers, then yes, it just might :D

Comment: My RewriteURL are correct, but i tried with any other line, like for example, just "ServerSignature Off" and it fails.

Comment: The RewriteURL may be correct, but the script doesn't automatically return the right `Content-Type`. PHP defaults to `text/html`, but if you're returning a JavaScript or CSS file you will want to send `application/javascript` and `text/css` respectively.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understood what you wrote last time, but the pages i am using to test out my the codes does not use any kind of RewriteURL, so when I remove the code and just add any single .htaccess line, it fails. So I am pretty sure its not the RewriteURL. Thanks though, i will remember this for future reference.